# ReportViewer for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reportviewer

VS2008 ReportViewer won't work in local mode with SQL 2008 reports (e.g. created with Report Builder 2.0). As far as I know that Beta2 includes updated report viewer: from [this topic](http://forums.asp.net/p/1513402/3613348.aspx) it seems that there's redistributable package.

The question: is there a way to make the new ReportViewer control to work with VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions (especially that fast) but I made it work with VS2008:

1. Get reportviewer.exe from location indicated at the link above or from the **cab6.cab** in the VS2010Beta2 disk.
2. Install it.
3. Copy Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll to your app's local dlls folder (\lib) and reference them in the project. Not sure if this is enough, I had to deploy/install reportviewer.exe anyway. But this is required to add references to VS2008.
4. Now the report viewer - at least, LocalReport used to generate PDFs - work.

I couldn't reference the assemblies in the GAC with VS2008 "Add Reference" - it only showed 9.0 versions. Don't know why, though of course it would be better to reference GAC assemblies. Will accept those who provide a fix for this.